# How to Prevent Page refresh on select change for dropdownlist in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a dropdownlist in my razor view MVC like

```
   @Html.DropDownListFor(n => n.EMP_ID, (SelectList)ViewBag.EmployeeList,  new { @id = "ddlemployee" },"---choose an Employee Name--").
```

I have applied select change event to drop-down using jquery, when select Employee name getting  Employee names and realted data, but problem is when i select a value in drop-down, dropdownlist setting again set to default first value,

It is not sticking to particular selected value, in terms of Asp.net terminology, how to prevent `postback` to `dropdownlist`?

```
        //Redirected to Controller  
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#ddlemployee").change(function () {
                location.href ='@Url.Action("GetEmployeeDetails", "Employer")'
            });
        });
        </script>

        //Action Method in Employer Controller
        public ActionResult GetEmployeeDetails(Timesheetmodel model)
        {
        try
        {
            ViewBag.EmployeeList = objts.getEmployeeNames();

            var emps = from n in db.TIMESHEETs
                       where n.RES_ID == model.EMP_ID
                       select n;
            int count = emps.Count();

            foreach (TIMESHEET ts in emps)
            {
                model.PROJ_ID = ts.PROJ_ID;
                model.SUN_HRS = ts.SUN_HRS;
                model.MON_HRS = ts.MON_HRS;
                model.TUE_HRS = ts.TUE_HRS;
                model.WED_HRS = ts.WED_HRS;
                model.THU_HRS = ts.THU_HRS;
                model.FRI_HRS = ts.FRI_HRS;
                model.SAT_HRS = ts.SAT_HRS;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return View("Timesheet", model);
    }
```

Comment: I dont understand question.. When you change dropdown, page refreshs or after page refresh dropdown's selected value changes to default?

Comment: I mean when I selecting a value in dropdown list, displaying data Employee data with reference to Employee name on table,  But problem is when i select after getting data, dropdownlist showing again as "choose an Employee", instead of what i selected, it should be stick to value what i selected. @JhoonBey

Comment: http is a statless protocol, so after the page is getting refreshed it loses all the data. You have to do an partial postback instead of entire postback.See my answer for more details

Comment: ok. how can i use "ajax dropdownlistfor" in mvc3

Comment: Please add your partial view code that loads the employee data and the controller action as well.

Comment: @MuraliMurugesan If i add that it will confuse more, can u help me that only prevent page refresh for only dropdowlist, is there any alternative select change event asynchronously like "html.dropdownlistfor"??

Comment: @Sanjay, with out seeing your implementation we are so much confuse, why it does refresh the page? Changing the dropdown value will never do post-back like web forms, until you submit your form :)

Comment: can you show your jquery select event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.

Passing Empid as querystring from jquery like:

```
       <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#ddlemployee").change(function () {
                debugger;
                var empid = $("#ddlemployee").val();
                location.href = '@Url.Action("GetEmployeeDetails", "Employer")?empid=' + empid ;

        });
    });
       </script>
```

and assign       "empid "   to model "Empid"  in Action method before foreach loop like

```
        model.EMP_ID = empid;//in Controller Action Method before foreachloop of my code
                             // and this model.EMP_ID binded to dropdownlist.
```

this EMP_ID passes same id to dropdownlist which was selected. Thats it.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.Net Webforms achieve **StateFullness** by using Some thing called **ViewState**

It is implemented as **hidden fields** in the page to hold data between requests.

This way , asp.net webforms achieves post back mechanism and was able to hold values in bewteen the requests.

Since **Http is a stateless protocol** , which means it has no relation between requests.

`View State` is **absent** in **ASP.Net MVC**.

So, you have to stop postback by partially posting back . Which means that you need to send an asynchronous request with out refreshing whole page.

It is possible by using AJAX. You can either use

```
 MVC Ajax or Jquery Ajax.
```

By using **AJax**, we can `eliminate` the `post back` and then do the **partial post back**.

**Solution:**

```
$("#dropdownid").change(function(event e)
{
     //Make your ajax request here..
});
```

Hope this helps

**Updated:**

```
$("#dropdownid").change(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        url: /*Your URL*/,
        success: function (data) {
            //do your callback operation  
        }                  
    });
});
```

Comment: How it possible?, Just I want redirect to Controller using Asynchronous request..?? can u give me clue.

Comment: @Sanjay..see my updated answer. You are hitting the controller asynchronously and getting the data from the server and filling the retireved data in the html page. it does not reload the dropdown there by the originally selected dropdown value presists